# SciFi Movie like The Hidden

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Looking for SciFi Movie like The Hidden. This movie is more campy, not as intense. The alien takes on the form I believe, of it’s last subject to have come in contact with.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if that helps you elicit more details.

Comment: This is quite broad; to improve this with details that are really useful to us for finding the movie, see [our well-written guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999). For starters, around when did you see it and/or how old do you think it is? Where was it from?

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to go on here, but this question definitely made me think of *[Amanda and the Alien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanda_and_the_Alien)*, which was a 1995 made-for-tv movie.  When I saw it, I remember thinking that *Amanda and the Alien* felt (at least thematically) a lot like a sillier version of *The Hidden*.

Per Wikpedia:

> Amanda Patterson, an employee at an upscale clothing store, is leading a relatively lonely and unremarkable life. All this changes when an alien that's been held at a secret military installation escapes by taking over the body of one of the base employees. Amanda finds the fugitive alien and decides to help him hide from the government agents chasing him, a seemingly easy task, as the alien must change host bodies every few days.